# primefaces file upload not appearing secondaly after update in ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.1.4, jsf 2.2.4, I inserted in a panel p: fileupload mode = "advanced",when I upload  a file the first time it Works,the panel is updated in Ajax mode, the second time when I want reuploader a new file the component disappears

Comment: Hi mira, please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Otherwise you might not get a lot of help

Comment: The code. Where is the code?